# Should I move to another country when my parents don't want to move with me?

Tags: parents, family

I am a 26 Male and I live in a country where I want to speak up against the oppression around me but I fear that if I do, mine and my loved ones lives would be endangered.

Therefore, I want to move to a different country and then marry and settle there at least until things get better in my home country.

But my parents don't want to come along with me and leave our home country. They even don't like the idea of me moving abroad myself.

I have one brother who is about the same age as me and also unmarried and we stay with our parents. My parents don't get along well with eachother and therefore often want to keep the two of us around so as to maintain a homely feeling in a not-so-good marriage.

Now my question, is it fine for me to move abroad and then work towards a greater cause of fighting oppression and fixing things while sitting in a country where if I speak up, I couldn't be threatened or kidnapped?

Or should I stay with my parents so that they're pleased with me, but at the cost of keeping my head down and not speaking up against all the injustice around me?

One thing I haven't figured out is that if I move abroad and my parents or brother are still here, there is also an off chance that when they can't reach me, they could possibly use my family here as bait or compensation, and I fear that too.

Comment: Usually one group of oppressors is overthrown only to be replaced by another group of oppressors.  Perhaps you should leave the country, get married, settle down, and not fight at all(?)

Comment: That's not good advice as a Muslim.

Answer (score -1):

Salaamu Alaikum,

Ahki there are more than one way to fight oppression, there is no reason for you to move away to do so. Charity for example, or helping out your local Islamic center is a great way to strive in the cause of Allah. Do not over burden yourself.

In my personal opinion, I think you should stay at home and take care of your parents, if they are arguing a lot then be a mediator for them.

If you want to speak out against oppression that is wonderful. Save money, travel to a protest or a rally, or support one from a far but leaving your family is a very difficult thing to do.

Again this is my personally opinion, stay with your family, donate to charity, travel to a protest or rally, find and support those in areas that need help. Stay with your family.

the ultimate decision is yours and inshallah you make a choice you are satisfied with.

Allahu A'lam